# How to provide information to canDeactivate in Aurelia view-model

Tags: aurelia

I am using `canDeactivate()` in a view-model. There is a way for the user to navigate away from the view where `canDeactivate` should not do its checks and just return true (in this case, when the user presses a Back button which is in another view). It appears that `canDeactivate` does not take any arguments (such as the params passed to `router.navigateToRoute`). If it did, I could indicate that the Back button was pressed in the params arg when calling `navigateToRoute`. What would be a good way to give `canDeactivate` this needed piece of information?

Comment: did you manage to find a solution to this problem yet?

Comment: Yes. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply imported the other view-model (in this case a navbar) which contains the state for the Back button.

Answer (score 1):

starting in aurelia-router 1.4.0, canDeactivate is passed an argument which contains the information you need to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question... Anyway, you can access class properties inside `canDeactivate()`. For instance:

```
canDeactivate() {
   //before calling router.navigateToRoute
   //you can set some properties to indicate the origin, the pressed button or wathever

   if (this.someProperty === true) {
      return true;
   }

   return false;
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question -- OP is asking how to tell canDeactivate() where it's navigating to, in order to inform the decision of whether you can deactivate or not.